# Java BitTorrent library

Tags: java, bittorrent

Are there any decent BitTorrent libraries for Java?  I need to program a simple torrent client, but it would be great if I didn't have to write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Snark](http://www.staging.threerings.net/snark.html) by Three Rings is a very lightweight bitorrent library that will give you basic torrent features.

Was [originally](http://www.klomp.org/snark/) written by Mark Wielaard. A github source can be found here https://github.com/akerigan/born-again-snark

Comment: "Snark is released under the GPL" (!)

Comment: @uckel, fixed the link.  Thanks.  The project must have moved.

Comment: Link works now. But the links on the linked page are broken.

Comment: Links within project page still broken as of today.

Comment: Link to snark is broken again

Answer (score 32):

Turn's [TTorrent](http://mpetazzoni.github.io/ttorrent/) is a pure Java bit torrent library.

Comment: [Etsy uses ttorrent](http://codeascraft.com/2012/01/23/solr-bittorrent-index-replication/) for Solr index replication.

Comment: As of 2017 it's for the most part abandoned and unmaintained. For everyone interested in Java BitTorrent I'd suggest checking out Bt, a modern Java 8 BitTorrent library: https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/bt . It includes: PEX, magnet links, DHT, message stream encryption, extended protocol. As a bonus it has clear and concise API and JavaDoc and, being built with Guice DI, provides vast possibilities for extension/customization.

Comment: There are important nuances that need to know. Ttorrent - does not support DHT. BT library - supported, only Android 8+

Answer (score 6):

I have created a [Bitlet Fork](https://github.com/Toilal/bitlet) on Github.

It's LGPLed, and it's running faster than ttorent.

Comment: Looks like bitlet made it onto github themselves in the end https://github.com/bitletorg/bitlet

Answer (score 4):

[Azureus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/azureus/) (now named [Vuze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuze)) gives you a plugin API. Using this API you can plug your code into Azureus. Start it inside your program, and listen/respond to its events.

Answer (score 3):

Azureus is written in Java - is most likely not "simple" but quite likely "decent" :)

Comment: But is it a library - does it offer APIs that you can easily use in your own programs?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to answer from jjnguy  : The code seems to be at http://code.google.com/p/snark/ and not in the repo pointed to in the link you've provided.

I've not used it, but a Google search showed up [YAIRCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yaircc/). Describes itself as "A lightweight Java Bittorrent library and client".

Answer (score -1):

Transdroid and Transdroid-desktop are libraries for adroid, that can also be used in java to control existing torrent clients.