# Is there a bittorent client I can easily programatically control from java?

Tags: java, bittorrent

A client wants to add functionality to a system that will distribute large files(~700mb) among 20 servers. The system is written in java. Bittorent seems like a perfect solution for this, is there client available that will allow me to add/remove torrents and track torrent progress programatically from java?

Comment: Check this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Java BitTorrent library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library)

See also: [Java Bitorrent API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitext/)

Answer (score 1):

Some torrent clients have web-interfaces. You can write a program to interact with this web-interface.

I have a Ruby program that interacts with uTorrent web interface. This is a pretty simple approach (RESTful interface with data being exchanged in JSON).