# What to use for torrents downloading with Java?

Tags: java, bittorrent

I know that there is Vuze API and jBitTorrent library but I can't use Vuze because of I have server without GUI and jBitTorrent is too old and too buggy. Can you tell me that bittorrent library for Java is good now? I need to download files through torrent file only. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library

Comment: This is 2009 year and I know all this libraries and tryed to use. But they are not updated since '09 or like Vuze API need gui to work. Read my post more carefully please :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to [run Vuze headless through it's console ui](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Console_UI).

When I tried it with the apt-gettable Vuze on Ubuntu, I didn't need to 'grab a few support jars' as the wiki linked above specified - it just ran straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transmission or µTorrent, or just run Vuze headless. With sending files to Transmission, you need to encode the binary data as base 64, with sending them to µTorrent, you need to use a multipart form via HTTP POST.

Here are their API pages:

https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt
http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi