# Parse info from torrent file

Tags: java, php, c++

I want to get information from *.torrent files. I've read that I can get a list of files of all torrent, announces, size of each piece and count of pieces.

1. Can you advise me a lib or class for php for a server-side program (in the other way, I can do C++/Java desktop utility and upload on server it's output information, so it's suitable too) for easily parsing this info?
2. Can I get info about offset and count of pieces for each file? For example, I want to choose only one file from each other. Can I get data for requesting only this file from peers?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library

Comment: Maybe this question matches your problem, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3593215/1109377