# Creating a torrent client in Java?

Tags: java, networking, p2p, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java BitTorrent library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library)

I would like to know more about creating a torrent client in java.
I ask this question here because i do not know which direction do i look into to start programming for a torrent client.
I guess i would require a

1. Socket
2. Knowledge of the networking torrents use

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need much more experience and research.  We cannot do that for you. Google for 'BitTorrent Specification'. You will need a bit more than one socket...

Comment: Yes i know will need much more research. And i am prepared to do that. Don't worry i would never ask anyone to do that for me :D

Answer (score 5):

The Java Socket API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

The Official BitTorrent Protocol Specification:
http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

Comment: Thank you. i shall look into it. will keep you posted.