# BitTorrent protocol with Java - Bitfield after successful handshake

Tags: java, network-programming, nio, network-protocols, bittorrent

Having successfully sent and received handshakes from multiple peers, the next step in the BitTorrent message chain is the **bitfield** message.

The **bitfield** message looks like below, where the top line explainins the byte-size of the protocol segments:

```
<4-bytes><1-byte><x-bytes>
<nrOfBits><identifier><bits>
```

The problem I have is that nearly all peers seem to be sending bitfield messages that differ from the above representation! The messages tend to look like this:

```
size: 332, [0, 0, 0, 112, 5, 127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -17...]
```

**The first problem** is that the majority of the messages I receive have length bytes:

```
 [0, 0, 0, 112]
```

even though the received message in this case contains 332 bytes in total, while at some other instances the message may only be 80 bytes or so.

**The second problem** is that the bits usually are repeating **-1** or some other strange negative value..

I don't think this can be attributed to low-level encoding problems on my side however, since other messages works fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

TCP, which I assume you're using, is a steam protocol. Messages come in never-ending streams of bytes. You have to divide the stream into individual messages yourself. The fact that you've read 332 bytes from the socket in a single read doesn't mean that you've read a single message. Bit torrent clients often pipeline messages (sending multiple messages at a time, without waiting for the answer). If the length is [0,0,0,112] then the length of the message is 4 + 1 + 111 (4 bytes of length, one byte for the identifier, and 111 bitfield bytes). That's it. After these 116 bytes comes the next message.

Edit: the same is true about uTP, the uTorrent UDP-based transport protocol despite the fact that it's based on the datagram oriented UDP.

**Problem #2:**

What you're seeing is an array of bytes, which are ALWAYS unsigned in java (which is really annoying). Their range is always between -128 and 127, so when the first (most significant bit) is set, java considers the byte value to be negative. This way if a bit-field has a byte with all 8 bits set (binary 11111111), you'll get a byte value of -1 since binary 11111111 corresponds to -1 in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). I suggest looking at these bytes in either binary form, or in hex (using something like `Integer.toHexString(myByte & 0xff)`).

Edit: On a different note, unless you're writing code just for the heck of it, I suggest [using a ready-made Java BitTorrent library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944530/java-bittorrent-library?rq=1). There's very little sense in writing this kind of stuff from scratch yourself when there are existing, well tested, libraries that implement everything you need and then some.